# What hotel search engines let you list and/or filter the free cancelation deadline?

Tags: online-resources, accommodation-search-engines

When searching for accommodations, many engines let you filter by free cancelation, such as Kayak, Hotels.com, Booking.com, Priceline and others. The problem is when clicking through the listings, some have restrictions on the deadline to cancel a reservation for free, such as a certain number of days before. And to find this information, the tools I used required me to click on the listing to open the page on a new tab, wait for it to load, find the information within the page, etc.

Is there a booking web site that lets you **filter by free cancelation on the day of the check-in**, or even select the deadline day for this option? If not, how about **listing the deadline information as part of the search results**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the most usable solution for filtering, but Google Search Engine and Google Maps let you see the see cancelation deadline on different options when you click on the specific listing. At least you don't have to go on the website and dig into that information and save some time:

[image]

Comment: As I think you start to say, I would still confirm the free cancellation applies by checking with the hotel. Google is usually accurate, but if it's vital to OP, I'd use Google to narrow down hotels then check their site/email them individually to make positive.

Comment: and "free cancellation" may only apply to the specific room rate/room plan being listed - other rate plans for the _same room at the same hotel_ may _not_ have free cancellation as described (or have other limits).  the individual listing rules, in general.